# Close a file pointer in Cuda (nvcc)

Tags: cuda, compiler-errors, nvcc

In gcc, the close function is used to close the file pointer. However my nvcc complier will not allow that. I can't seem to find a cuda-specific call or alias.

Is there a special cuda file pointer close?

This is the error I get.
`error: identifier "close" is undefined`

For this simple code;
`FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }`

`close(fp);`

Comment: Try fclose(). Nvcc is not touching the code, it is being compiled with your host compiler and the error and the question have nothing to do with CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When **NVCC** compiles your `.cu` file, it delegates the compilation of the C/C++ parts of the file to your native C/C++ compiler (**gcc** in your case). So, the error is coming from gcc.

You need to check why gcc is producing this error for the code in this file. Most probably, you have not included the necessary header file where `close()` is defined, `unistd.h`. Or try `fclose()` as another commenter has suggested.